# Bootstrap modal not dismissing after form submit in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble with a bootstrap modal in my Rails 3 app. It currently handles a review form that submits and updates the DB just fine, but the modal doesn't close when the form is submitted. I've tried adding this to the form submit button:

```
:data => {:dismiss => "modal"}
```

But it closes the modal without executing the update action. Here's my modal code as it stands:

```
<!-- Review Modal -->
<% if current_user == nil %>
<% else %>
<div id="reviewModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="reviewModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="reviewModalLabel">Write a review</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  <%= form_for(review_ballot, :remote => true, :html => {:class => 'review_ballot'}) do |f| %>
    <h4>Your score:</h4>
    <%= f.label("score_1", content_tag(:span, '1'), {:class=>"review", :id=>"1"}) %>
    <%= radio_button_tag("review[score]", 1, current_user_review == 1, :class => 'review_button')%>
    <%= f.label("score_2", content_tag(:span, '2'), {:class=>"review", :id=>"2"}) %>
    <%= radio_button_tag("review[score]", 2, current_user_review == 2, :class => 'review_button')%>
    <%= f.label("score_3", content_tag(:span, '3'), {:class=>"review", :id=>"3"}) %>
    <%= radio_button_tag("review[score]", 3, current_user_review == 3, :class => 'review_button')%>
    <%= f.label("score_4", content_tag(:span, '4'), {:class=>"review", :id=>"4"}) %>
    <%= radio_button_tag("review[score]", 4, current_user_review == 4, :class => 'review_button')%>
    <%= f.label("score_5", content_tag(:span, '5'), {:class=>"review", :id=>"5"}) %>
    <%= radio_button_tag("review[score]", 5, current_user_review == 5, :class => 'review_button')%>
  <br />
    <h4>What'd you think?</h4>
  <%= f.text_area :review_text, :rows => 3, :cols => 10 %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :venue_id, @venue.id %>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <%= submit_tag "Save review", :class => "btn btn-warning" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the venue helper for the review_ballot method

```
module VenuesHelper
  def review_ballot
    if @review = current_user.reviews.find_by_venue_id(params[:id])
      @review
    else
      current_user.reviews.new
    end
  end

  def current_user_review
    if @review = current_user.reviews.find_by_venue_id(params[:id])
      @review.score
    else
      "N/A"
    end
  end
end
```

I'm at a loss for what to try now. I've Googled around and haven't had any luck. How do I fix this?

Edit: My temporary solution - I've removed `:remote => true` from the modal and redirected the visitor in the controller action, so now I don't have to worry about it being dismissed.

It's obviously clunky/hacky, so I'd still love it if someone could help me solve this. Willing to provide more code/info on demand.

Comment: have you tried adding a `data-dismiss="modal"` to the submit button ? On the other side, i usually use modals for ajax calls, and i usually close them with a JS callback on ajax complete - this way you can add a loader image to the modal while the action is processing, and handle errors gracefully (replace the modal body, etc.)

Comment: Yeah, I added data-dismiss, but that closes the modal before the form has a chance to submit so it doesn't show up in the DB.

Comment: I've been trying to use a function similar to this for a bit:
`$('#reviewModal').on('ajax:complete',function(){$('#reviewModal').modal('hide');});`

With no success...

Comment: weird, that's what i usually do and it works. where do you place this script ?

Comment: It's in the venues.js file. I have a `content_for :scripts` clause at the top of this particular view that references it.

Comment: just to be sure, have you wrapped your script in a `$(document).ready` ?

Comment: Here's the full code: `$(document).ready(
    $('#reviewModal').on('ajax:complete',function(){$('#reviewModal').modal('hide');
    })
  );`

Comment: my usual js looks like : `$(document).ready( $('#your_form_id').bind('ajax:complete',function(){$('#reviewModal').modal('hide'); }) );`. Notice that i target the form, and use `bind` instead of `on`. Hope that helps...

Answer (score 3):

In Your case, I mean You are not uploading any images. So you can simply go for ajax calling to submit. Here is a simple code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#submit_button_id').click(function() {  
    var valuesToSubmit = $("#form_id").serialize();
    $("#modal_id").modal('hide') ;

    $.ajax({
      url: "/controller/method",
      data: valuesToSubmit,
      type: "POST/GET/PUT"
      }).success(function(data, status){
        $("#id_if_div_where_you_want_to_show_updated_data").html( data );
    });

    return false; 
  });
});
```

**Edited**

Controller method looks like the following

```
def method
  Do what you want to do
  @object = Model.some_queries
  render :template => "path_to_view_file like controller_name/method_name", :layout => false
end
```

Comment: once I've fixed my controller so it accepts ajax calls with `respond_to do |format| format.json...` how do I update my view? With a `create.js.erb` file? I can't get that to work. Thanks Jyothu

Comment: @Brian : Its not a submission using remote => true, We are using only ajax for this purpose. See my answer's edit part. It may help you.

Comment: how do I set up the route for that method, something like: `match 'users/update_dom', :to => "users#update_dom"`?

Comment: Can you take a look at the question I just posted? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462138/update-dom-after-modal-form-submission-is-handled-using-rails-json  I am trying to do this in the `users#create` controller method.

Comment: @Brian : in your routes.rb, DO one thing. "resources :users do
    member do
      put :update_dom
    end
  end"

Answer (score 0):

I have worked around this problem by binding submit to the `hidden.bs.modal` event:

```
$('#modal_id').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $('form').submit();
    form_submitted = false;
});
```

To prevent the form from submitting on the button click, you can use `return false;` in the onclick event of the form:

```
<%= submit_tag 'Save review',
               class: 'btn btn-warning',
               :data => { :dismiss => 'modal' },
               :onclick => "form_submitted = true; return false;" %>
```

**Edit:**

Added `form_submitted = true` to onclick event, so you know the modal closed on submit rather than any other exit condition. Reset to false once `$('form').submit()` has been called. Add this variable to your javascript file, initially false.