# How to update DOM after modal form submission on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to handle my sign up process with modal forms, using Twitter Bootstrap. I can get the form to submit, the modal to close, and everything works fine, except the DOM is not unobtrusively updated.

After a user signs in, the navigation bar (which is rendered with a partial and has ruby in it) should no longer have a link for "Sign up", and it should acquire a link "Sign out".

Since I can't use `render` in my coffeescript file which manages the form submission, how can I re-render the nav bar so to speak to make it reflect the successful sign up/modal form submission?

**Modal Form (HAML):**

```
= simple_form_for @user, remote: true, html: {data: {type: 'html'}, class: 'form-horizontal'} do |f|
  %div.modal-header
    %button.close{"aria-hidden" => "true", "data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"} ×
    - if @user.errors.any?
      #error_explanation
        %h2= "#{pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this user from being saved:"
        %ul
          - @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
            %li= msg
  %div.modal-body
    =render 'form', f: f
  %div.modal-footer
    = f.button :submit, name: 'Sign Up', class: "btn-primary", id: "new_user_button"
    =link_to "Sign In", signin_path
```

**jquery handling form submission:**

```
$ ->
    $("#new_user_button").click ->
      valuesToSubmit = $("#new_user").serialize()
      $("#signup_modal").modal "hide"
      $.ajax(
        url: "/users"
        data: valuesToSubmit
        type: "POST"
      ).success (data, status) ->
            #update the DOM?
```

**Controller:**

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    respond_to do |format| 
      if @user.save
              #SignupMailer.new_subscriber(@user).deliver
              sign_in @user
              format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "Thank you for signing up!" }
              format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
              # format.js {'create'}
            else
              format.html { render action: "new" }
              format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
              #format.js
            end
    end
```

**Navigation Partial (HAML):**
need to unobtrusively change these elements after form submission and modal close!

```
%ul.nav.nav-pills.pull-right
  -if signed_in?
    %li{:class => "#{'active' if current_page?(user_path(current_user))}"}=link_to "Your page", user_path(current_user)
    %li=link_to "Sign out", signout_path, :class => "#{'active' if current_page?(root_path)}"   
  -else
    %li= link_to_modal 'Sign Up', new_user_path, :width=> "600", :height =>"400", :remote => true, :id => "new_user_link"
    %li=link_to "Sign In", signin_path, :class => "#{'active' if current_page?(root_path)}"
```

Comment: I think you better reload the page. It's a lot of hassle to replace all elements that are user-dependent (and even if now there's only one doesn't mean it will be that way)

Comment: fair enough...i've become so fixated on making it work, it didn't really occur to me to just go around the issue. However, if you know of a general paradigm to apply to this case, I'd love to hear it. I appreciate the level-headed advice thought